# Rotate image left or right onTouch

Tags: android, mobile

So I have square in the center of my screen. Right now i have a 2 buttons to rotate left and right.

```
switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.leftClick:
                square.setRotation(square.getRotation() - 90);

                break;

            case R.id.rightClick:
                square.setRotation(square.getRotation() + 90);

                break;

            default:

                break;
        }
```

I'd like to change it to do so by touch. Possibly by vertical half (the horizontal bottom half) of the screen. If that make sense. I'm also curious if its possible to have an animation go along with the rotation. Any tips? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Also, the square is a bitmap image:CODE:
square = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.square);

Comment: @karaokyo nothing really. I'm really confused about touch events.

Answer (score 1):

@cookiemonster: You can use ***RotateAnimation*** for your requirement . [RotateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/RotateAnimation.html) An animation that controls the rotation of an object. This rotation takes place in the X-Y plane. You can specify the point to use for the center of the rotation, `where (0,0) is the top left point`. If not specified, `(0,0) is the default rotation point`. Please check below demo link .I hope it will help .

### [A simple animation to rotate an image with finger touch both left and right.](http://andygeeks.blogspot.in/2014/05/how-to-animate-image-to-rotate-with.html)

Comment: This is good, but isn't what I was looking for. The square has a color on each side. I'd like to be able to tap left and right to rotate to change which color is on top.

Comment: Unfortunately no, I simply wanted to build spinny square, from iOS store, on to android platform. Project got a bit annoying. Couldn't fully figure it out.